# Some scripts stopped working after SSL installation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ssl, https

I use the following code to print the contents inside a div element. This worked fine for me until I installed a SSL certificate in my server. The code still functions if I access the page via `http://`. However it is not working when the same page is accessed via `https://`. I need help solving this problem.

```
function PrintElem(elem)
{
    Popup($(elem).html());
}

function Popup(data) 
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'Business Sense Chart', 'height=600,width=1200');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Business Sense Analytics</title>'); 
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body><center>');
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.document.write('</center></body></html>');
    mywindow.print();
    return true;
}
```

**Note**: When I used firebug to diagnose the bug, it showed the error "$ is not a function". Similar other scripts are facing the same problem.

Comment: Are you perhaps including the script using a `http` link (instead of `https`). Browsers block non-secure content by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Note: When I used firebug to diagnose the bug, it showed the error "$ is not a function". Similar other scripts are facing the same problem.

You are most likely loading jQuery off an HTTP URL (CDN, perhaps?), which causes browsers to block it as insecure. All assets - images, scripts, CSS, etc. - need to be HTTPS on a HTTPS page.

Comment: I am using HTTPS to include jQuery and other stuffs.

Comment: `$ is not a function` means either jQuery didn't load or you're doing stuff with jQuery before it gets included. Check Firebug and ensure the HTTPS request to jQuery is working.

Comment: Ok. will check that again and post back.

Comment: Well I made a small mistake. I referenced to jQuery and jQuery-UI files hosted in jQuery server without knowing that they don't have SSL installed in their server. Now I changed references to google`s server and they are working fine. Thank You.